# Has anyone succeed in using 'yield' keyword inside jython scripts for Grinder 3?

Tags: python, jython, yield, grinder

I'm have this function:

```
def ngrams(word):
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        yield word[:i]
```

..and I got an error

```
2012-03-09 19:37:31,928 ERROR worker-bootstrap: Error running worker process
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('C:\\grinder-3.7.1\\lib
\\.\\nb-romg-file-store\\current\\grinder_test.py', 72, 15, '        yield word[:i]  '))
        (no code object) at line 0
```

Is there any way to make `yield` work? I tried the same function in `jython` console - if works normally.

Comment: Which Jython version are they using?

Comment: That's not an *n*-grams generator, btw. It's a prefixes generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older versions of Jython, generators (functions using the `yield` keyword) are not available by default. You can try enabling the feature by adding

```
from __future__ import generators
```

to the top of your source file. If this doesn't work, you're probably out of luck and generators simply are not available in that version of Jython. In that case, you can try to simulate the behaviour using lists:

```
def ngrams(word):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        result.append(word[:i])
    return result
```

This is dead ugly, but it should work even in the most ancient Python implementations.